# Display shipping with inc and ex vat value on checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout

How to display shipping charge inc and ex tax on the checkout.

For example

```
3.25 [ex. VAT] 3.99 [inc. VAT]
```

on panel where you choose shipping method.

Cant see obvious configuration so assume template override?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Store/Configuration/Sales/Tax/Tax Classes`, you may set the valid tax class for the setting **Tax Class for Shipping**

Once this is set, you can troubleshoot the issue with the function `\Magento\Tax\Helper\Data::getShippingPrice`
and even better at `\Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector::processShippingTaxInfo`

If your system has no customisation and if the above configuration area is setup like the screenshot below, the rendering should display

[image]

[image]

*Note: this is tested with Magento ver. 2.3.3 and luma theme + sample data.*

Comment: Completely makes sense. With all that in place I still get method.price_excl_tax and method.price_incl_tax as same value in KO. Yet calculations are correct as correct elsewhere in quote totals. Something somewhere must be overriding but I'm yet to pinpoint it.

Comment: now, when ko is in the game, it is possibly either a listener not being connected or the customer data not being updated. Have you been able to track the shipping data in the locaStorage for instance?

Comment: I suspect you are right with customer-data. 'selectedShippingAddress' was null - now it isn't but still same. But other irregularities exist. I've run out of time to debug this unfortunately.